# Import .sql file in R

Tags: sql, r, database, import

I have a .sql file in my hard drive but I am not able to import it in R using RODBC package or RmySQL package.

It seems to work only on a SQL server.

Is there a way to import this file ?
Or can I convert it to CSV and then import it to R ?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Is there any error you are facing. If yes, plz post the same

Comment: The thing is that I cannot even find the command to import the database with the 2 packages that I mentionned.
I know that I have to link the database with ODBC but in the administration tools, I cannot add a sql connection ...

Comment: as far as I know, .sql is a simple text file. What do you want? To process query written in the file and return a result to an R `data.frame` ?

Comment: Yes, I want to open it, explore it, and then do some filtering /requests.
But I need to have access to the headers first .
Thanks

Comment: To be more precise, I would like to understand the structure of the data, and then import it partially using R ... (it is a 2GB database).
It is the first time I am working on a .sql file.

Comment: Not knowing more details, I could imagine that you could use RSQLite to read it into a SQLite database and then access that database from R.  If you give more detail about your SQL file, I can elaborate.

Comment: What is in the .sql file?   Is it a text file that contains SQL statements?  If so, which database system are they for?  Can you provide a bit of the file in the question?

Comment: Hi , I don't know what is exactly inside, that is why I want to open it and explore it. But it should be a database ...
I am not able to open it in the notepad .
I will try to open it with RSQLite